# jquery window.onscroll listener to display:none and display:inline not appearing in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, scrolltop, onscroll

I am testing in Safari 11.0.3

Site: https://3milychu.github.io/met-erials

I have the following function to create a header that pops out the selected item upon scroll

```
function scrollState () {


var elmnt = document.getElementById("title");
var rep = elmnt.offsetTop;

if (window.pageYOffset >= elmnt.offsetHeight) { 
       // $('input:not(:checked').parent().hide();
       $('input:not(:checked').parent().css("display","none");
       $("input:checked").css("display", "inline");
        $("label").css("marginLeft", "35%");
       $("label" ).css("fontSize", "4em");
       $("label" ).css("textAlign", "center");
       $("input:checked").css("float", "none");
        $("input:checked").css("verticalAlign", "top");
       $("input[type=radio]").css("width", "3em");
       $("input[type=radio]").css("height", "3em");
        $("input:checked").css("fontSize", "0.5em");
} else  {
        $("input:checked").css("display", "inline")
        $("label").css("marginLeft", "0%");
        $("label" ).css("textAlign", "none");
       $("input:checked").css("float", "right");
       $("input[type=radio]").css("width", "2em");
       $("input[type=radio]").css("height", "2em");
        $("input:checked").css("fontSize", "11px");
        // $('input:not(:checked').parent().show();
        $('input:not(:checked').parent().css("display","inline-block");
        $("label").css("fontSize", "1.5em");

    };
};
```

I call it by:

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollState()};
```

Why is this not working in Safari? I commented out the .hide() method after seeing that Safari needs it to be replaced with .css("display","none").

This works in Chrome and Firefox as desired (when you use the .hide() and .show() methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a syntax error.

```
$('input:not(:checked').parent().css("display","inline-block");
```

should be

```
$('input:not(:checked)').parent().css("display","inline-block");
```

This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$('input:not(:checked').parent().css("display","none");` (the one that replaces `.show()`) needs to be `('display', 'inline-block')`? You want the element to show, but you are writing `('display', 'none')`

Comment: Thanks for catching that. It should be ("display", "inline-block"), I corrected it. Still doesn't work in Safari though.